# How to search the contents in the string With CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

there is a label applied CKEditor on my page, HTML code as follows:

```
<textarea id="MyHtmlEditor" class="ckeditor" cols="80" rows="10" name="MyHtmlEditor"></textarea>
```

When I upload and then insert a picture, you can see the pictures in normal CKEditor, the viewing source will appear `<img alt = "" src = File Name />` tag code.

Because it will put more than one picture, if I want to do in a certain period of time to execute javascript, you can get all the content in the editing area where CKEditor `<img alt = "" src = filename />` src attribute values

That is made all the pictures of connecting position.

I found a CKEditor stall, it seems that only the editorial content replace () method can be used.

Some people know how to reach this level?

Comment: Greetings and welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is hard to understand, could you try to make it a little more clear? I edited your question so that the `img` tags work in the question, but it's hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Hello, I was just wondering how search CKEditor text edit box.
And the ability to search out the information taken in to the array variable.

Thank you.